# Show "offline" page in MVC3 while updating database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have an MVC3 website backed by a SQL server db.
The db gets "refreshed" every night which can take around 30 mins.

During this time, I could take the app offline with an app_offline.htm file (and all of the issues that can cause).

The db refresh is controlled from a windows service, since part of this is to import text files from different sources.

I am wondering if there is a cleaner and nicer way to amend the site so that it shows a friendly "Database updating" type page, without taking the site offline?

Comment: So no interaction is possible with the site while the database upgrade is happening, right?

Comment: Almost none. There are some static pages and a very few that rely on tables that are not updated that ARE available: If its simpler, then I would rather redirect ALL pages.  But the app_offline is not only ugly, but since I am not updating any of the site itself, a little too draconian.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what issues can app_offline.htm cause?

Comment: @bamccaig: `Users`, pure and simple.  They see a page telling them to wait and they wait.  They see app_offline and phone the helpdesk...repeatedly...with email backup as well ;)

Comment: @BlueChippy: The users don't see `app_offline` here. The browser shows the requested URL, but the `app_offline.htm` file is served instead. It just gives them an explanation of why the site isn't working, that it's intentional, and to please be patient. :) Of course, it helps that there is no help desk for this application, and most of the users don't know who I am yet... >:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a `DatabaseDependant:ActionResultFilterAttribute` and applying it to all Action methods that require the DB (or the part of it that gets updated).
Applied it to some controllers as well where appropriate.

The filter simply checks a value (used the registry as opposed to app.config as allowed more shared access that the sites app.config) and either redirects or calls the base.

Comment: If the database is still readable (apart from the data being refreshed), I would store the offline flag in a metadata table there, so that the Windows service doesn't need to access the registry. I would also store a static last-time-checked flag in my application so that we are not hitting the db/registry on every request but can do so at 'n' minute intervals.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add a key the appSettings of your web.config, something like:

```
<add key="MaintenanceMode" value="true" />
```

Then you can use the Application_BeginRequest event in the global.asax file and check for the value of the key and redirect to a maintenance page.

Comment: I was looking at ActionRequestFilter - however, although this works, it also loops as it keeps calling itself!

Comment: How is this better than using app_offline.htm?

Comment: I can keep non-dependant pages up and running to allow the site to be accessed, but just deny access to pages that are dependant on the tables that are being updated.